# What I do select first/second or forth td content with XPath

Tags: dom, xpath, html-table, nodevalue

```html
<table class="attributes">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label title"><b>scale</b></td>
            <td class="value">1/48</td>
            <td class="label title"><b>products</b></td>
            <td class="value">Plastic kits</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Hit a brain block on this one...

Trying to capture specific values within the td's. So the first time around I'll grab the first, then the second and so on...

```
    //table[@class='attributes']/tbody/tr//descendant::td[@class='value']
```

Gives me all the td values how to select only the 2nd or 3rd.

I've tried:

```
    "//table[@class='attributes']/tbody/tr//descendant::td[@class='value']/td[2]"
```

With no success.

For example:

```
    $x("//*[@class='attributes']/tbody/tr/td[@class='value']")
```

finds me

```html
    [<td class=​"value">​1/48​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Plastic kits​</td>​, <td     class=​"value">​Limited edition​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Aircraft​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Eduard​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​0.5 kg​</td>​]
```

So then I changed the XPath to:

```
    $x("//*[@class='attributes']/tbody/tr/td[@class='value'][1]")
```

adding the [1] and what it does is returns

```html
    [<td class=​"value">​1/48​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Limited edition​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Eduard​</td>​]
```

Comment: link to img so far http://i435.photobucket.com/albums/qq74/gtspeed15/xpath.gif

Answer (score 4):

To select all of the `class='value'` `td` elements beneath the `class='attributes'` `table`:

```
/table[@class='attributes']//td[@class='value']
```

selects:

```
<td class="value">1/48</td>
<td class="value">Plastic kits</td>
```

To select just the second such `td`:

```
(/table[@class='attributes']//td[@class='value'])[2]
```

Comment: Nearly there added a link to image. It seems to grab the first set of      td's  the chrome xpath doesn't get anything strangely it seems to never really work well.

Comment: You may have a clear idea in your mind of which `td` you want, but the image you've added does not nail it down.  Nor does it say how what I've shown you for selecting the second `td` fails to meet your needs.

Comment: Sincere apologies if I haven't explained myself well. The linked image is the actual html I tried to simplify it a little. I can pin down the required td tree if that's the correct term. But it gives me 4 of them I only require on this instance the 1st at this moment then I can move onto the next few.

Comment: for example $x("//*[@class='attributes']/tbody/tr/td[@class='value']") finds me [<td class=​"value">​1/48​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Plastic kits​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Limited edition​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Aircraft​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Eduard​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​0.5 kg​</td>​] so then I changed the xpath to $x("//*[@class='attributes']/tbody/tr/td[@class='value'][1]") adding the [1] and what it does is returns [<td class=​"value">​1/48​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Limited edition​</td>​, <td class=​"value">​Eduard​</td>​]

Comment: Please update your question; it's too hard to read code in comments.  Thanks.

Comment: @Stuart: Answer generalized to cover what's tripping you up:  Add parenthesis to choose nth such node overall rather than each nth such node.